# Quarkus JWT - Fallback to JDBC authentication if JWT token is not present

Tags: quarkus

I'm using Quarkus to authenticate users with JWT RBAC. However, I would like to be able to authenticate users if JWT token is not present in HTTP header, with HTTP Basic username / password pair and a JDBC Realm. Is it possible with Quarkus ?

Answer (score 0):

**Basic Authentication**

To enable basic authentication set `quarkus.http.auth.basic=true`. You must also have at least one extension installed that provides a username/password based IdentityProvider, such as [Elytron JDBC](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jdbc).

More can be seen on: https://quarkus.io/guides/security#basic-authentication

Also check this: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/client_side_http_basic_access

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Authenticator implements ClientRequestFilter {

    private final String user;
    private final String password;

    public Authenticator(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
        final String basicAuthentication = getBasicAuthentication();
        headers.add("Authorization", basicAuthentication);

    }

    private String getBasicAuthentication() {
        String token = this.user + ":" + this.password;
        try {
            return "BASIC " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(token.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot encode with UTF-8", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is server side, not on client side. I already have elytron jdbc installed, but I would like to override authentication in case a JWT token is present in request header.